# How can i distribute work load across Azure app service instances?

Tags: azure

In Azure I have a app service and I have Scale Out to give it 15 Instance count. Reason is that the app picks up batches of 100 jobs nd runs them every 15 seconds.
But when i look at the instances and see how many are actually doing work , out of 15 there are  only about 7 of them.

Why arent the other 8 instances being allocated work to do ?
Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: When you put the scale out, you must have put some kind of condition how when to scale out? Have you confirmed that your metrics are meeting those conditions? Maybe 7 is enough to handle the load. They will not scale out if the conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the conditions that you have set for the autoscaling and where the bottle neck is. Assuming that the bottle neck is CPU and your scaling rule is CPU based.

The following scenario would give a max of 7 instances running.

- There is default 1 instance running
- The scaling rule is add **one** instance if the CPU is greater that 85% for one minute
- The batch job starts
- The auto scale rule is evaluated and one instance is added
- After 60 seconds auto scale rule is evaluated again and another instance is added
- This continues for another 5 mins, at which time 7 instances are running
- The job completes, there is not need to add extra instances

You configuration is probably different, but this illustrates what may be happening.

Comment: So then if i have 15 instances and  lets say jobs are running , then if 1 instances is running and it reaches 65% then a second instance is started , and so on , but by the 7th instances the first is gone down to 40% , then jobs are allocated to it . hence there may never be 15 instances running . Am i interpreting this correctly ?  If so , can i utilize all 15 instances by lets say reducing the condition to 30% ?

Comment: Also  where can i find these conditions in the Azure portal , cause when i scaled out there was no option for setting conditions , i used manual scaling , not rule based. When i try to use rule based it says "Rule based scaling will be ignored if Automatic scaling is enabled" ?

Comment: The scaling options that are available are dependent on the pricing tier that you are on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: The functionality that I was referring to was scale out rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json